# Adding new columns to viewer in wireshark

Tags: wireshark

How can I add new columns to wireshark packet viewer like source, destination etc.. I have written my custom dissector. but there is some information which I want to display in the packet viewer columns.
How shall I proceed with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with Edit->Preferences->User Interface->Columns.

There Custom field type for fields of custom dissectors.